# OpenCL Read Back bus speed extensive drop

Tags: buffer, opencl, bandwidth

I have a simple OpenCL host code, which is writing some amount of data into an OpenCL enabled device's buffer and then read it back into the host memory. It does this experiment for different buffer sizes. Here is the code I use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "support.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include "ResultDatabase.h"
#include "OptionParser.h"

using namespace std;

void addBenchmarkSpecOptions(OptionParser &op)
{
    op.addOption("nopinned", OPT_BOOL, "",
                 "disable usage of pinned (pagelocked) memory");
}

// Modifications:
//    Jeremy Meredith, Wed Dec  1 17:05:27 EST 2010
//    Added calculation of latency estimate.
void RunBenchmark(cl_device_id id,
                  cl_context ctx,
                  cl_command_queue queue,
                  ResultDatabase &resultDB,
                  OptionParser &op)
{
    bool verbose = op.getOptionBool("verbose");
    bool pinned = !op.getOptionBool("nopinned");
    int  npasses = op.getOptionInt("passes");
    const bool waitForEvents = true;

    // Sizes are in kb
    int nSizes  = 20;
    int sizes[20] = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,
                     32768,65536,131072,262144,524288};

    // Max sure we don't surpass the OpenCL limit.
    cl_long maxAllocSizeBytes = 0;
    clGetDeviceInfo(id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE,
                    sizeof(cl_long), &maxAllocSizeBytes, NULL);
    while (sizes[nSizes-1]*1024 > 0.90 * maxAllocSizeBytes)
    {
        --nSizes;
        if (verbose) cout << " - dropping allocation size to keep under reported limit.\n";
        if (nSizes < 1)
        {
            cerr << "Error: OpenCL reported a max allocation size less than 1kB.\b";
            return;
        }
    }

    // Create some host memory pattern
    if (verbose) cout << ">> creating host mem pattern\n";
    int err;
    float *hostMem1;
    float *hostMem2;
    cl_mem hostMemObj1;
    cl_mem hostMemObj2;
    long long numMaxFloats = 1024 * (sizes[nSizes-1]) / 4;
    if (pinned)
    {
        int err1, err2;
        hostMemObj1 = clCreateBuffer(ctx,
                                     CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                                     sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats, NULL, &err1);
        if (err1 == CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            hostMem1 = (float*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, hostMemObj1, true,
                                                  CL_MAP_READ|CL_MAP_WRITE,
                                                  0,sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats,0,
                                                  NULL,NULL,&err1);
        }
        hostMemObj2 = clCreateBuffer(ctx,
                                     CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                                     sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats, NULL, &err2);
        if (err2 == CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            hostMem2 = (float*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, hostMemObj2, true,
                                                  CL_MAP_READ|CL_MAP_WRITE,
                                                  0,sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats,0,
                                                  NULL,NULL,&err2);
        }
        while (err1 != CL_SUCCESS || err2 != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            // free the first buffer if only the second failed
            if (err1 == CL_SUCCESS)
                clReleaseMemObject(hostMemObj1);

            // drop the size and try again
            if (verbose) cout << " - dropping size allocating pinned mem\n";
            --nSizes;
            if (nSizes < 1)
            {
                cerr << "Error: Couldn't allocated any pinned buffer\n";
                return;
            }
            numMaxFloats = 1024 * (sizes[nSizes-1]) / 4;
            hostMemObj1 = clCreateBuffer(ctx,
                                         CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                                         sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats, NULL, &err1);
            if (err1 == CL_SUCCESS)
            {
                hostMem1 = (float*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, hostMemObj1, true,
                                                      CL_MAP_READ|CL_MAP_WRITE,
                                                      0,sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats,0,
                                                      NULL,NULL,&err1);
            }
            hostMemObj2 = clCreateBuffer(ctx,
                                         CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                                         sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats, NULL, &err2);
            if (err2 == CL_SUCCESS)
            {
                hostMem2 = (float*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, hostMemObj2, true,
                                                      CL_MAP_READ|CL_MAP_WRITE,
                                                      0,sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats,0,
                                                      NULL,NULL,&err2);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hostMem1 = new float[numMaxFloats];
        hostMem2 = new float[numMaxFloats];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<numMaxFloats; i++) {
        hostMem1[i] = i % 77;
        hostMem2[i] = -1;
    }

    // Allocate some device memory
    if (verbose) cout << ">> allocating device mem\n";
    cl_mem mem1 = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                                 sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats, NULL, &err);
    while (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        // drop the size and try again
        if (verbose) cout << " - dropping size allocating device mem\n";
        --nSizes;
        if (nSizes < 1)
        {
            cerr << "Error: Couldn't allocated any device buffer\n";
            return;
        }
        numMaxFloats = 1024 * (sizes[nSizes-1]) / 4;
        mem1 = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                              sizeof(float)*numMaxFloats, NULL, &err);
    }
    if (verbose) cout << ">> filling device mem to force allocation\n";
    Event evDownloadPrime("DownloadPrime");
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, mem1, false, 0,
                               numMaxFloats*sizeof(float), hostMem1,
                               0, NULL, &evDownloadPrime.CLEvent());
    CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);
    if (verbose) cout << ">> waiting for download to finish\n";
    err = clWaitForEvents(1, &evDownloadPrime.CLEvent());
    CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);

    // Three passes, forward and backward both
    for (int pass = 0; pass < npasses; pass++)
    {
        // store the times temporarily to estimate latency
        //float times[nSizes];
        // Step through sizes forward on even passes and backward on odd
        for (int i = 0; i < nSizes; i++)
        {
            int sizeIndex;
            if ((pass%2) == 0)
                sizeIndex = i;
            else
                sizeIndex = (nSizes-1) - i;

            // Read memory back from the device
            if (verbose) cout << ">> reading from device "<<sizes[sizeIndex]<<"kB\n";
            Event evReadback("Readback");
            err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, mem1, false, 0,
                                       sizes[sizeIndex]*1024, hostMem2,
                                       0, NULL, &evReadback.CLEvent());
            CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);

            // Wait for event to finish
            if (verbose) cout << ">> waiting for readback to finish\n";
            err = clWaitForEvents(1, &evReadback.CLEvent());
            CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);

            if (verbose) cout << ">> finish!";
            if (verbose) cout << endl;

            // Get timings
            err = clFlush(queue);
            CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);
            evReadback.FillTimingInfo();
            if (verbose) evReadback.Print(cerr);

            double t = evReadback.SubmitEndRuntime() / 1.e6; // in ms
            //times[sizeIndex] = t;

            // Add timings to database
            double speed = (double(sizes[sizeIndex] * 1024.) /  (1000.*1000.)) / t;
            char sizeStr[256];
            sprintf(sizeStr, "% 7dkB", sizes[sizeIndex]);
            resultDB.AddResult("ReadbackSpeed", sizeStr, "GB/sec", speed);

            // Add timings to database
            double delay = evReadback.SubmitStartDelay() / 1.e6;
            resultDB.AddResult("ReadbackDelay", sizeStr, "ms", delay);
            resultDB.AddResult("ReadbackTime", sizeStr, "ms", t);
        }
        //resultDB.AddResult("ReadbackLatencyEstimate", "1-2kb", "ms", times[0]-(times[1]-times[0])/1.);
        //resultDB.AddResult("ReadbackLatencyEstimate", "1-4kb", "ms", times[0]-(times[2]-times[0])/3.);
        //resultDB.AddResult("ReadbackLatencyEstimate", "2-4kb", "ms", times[1]-(times[2]-times[1])/1.);
    }

    // Cleanup
    err = clReleaseMemObject(mem1);
    CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);
    if (pinned)
    {
        err = clReleaseMemObject(hostMemObj1);
        CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);
        err = clReleaseMemObject(hostMemObj2);
        CL_CHECK_ERROR(err);
    }
    else
    {
        delete[] hostMem1;
        delete[] hostMem2;
    }
}
```

while running the code and plotting the speed against the buffer size, I see this:
[image]

As you can see, the performance drops for data sizes over 1024KB. And then stays the same at some point.

My Device is a Tesla K40 and I'm using Nvidia's OpenCL driver. But still do not understand the main reason behind such a weird behaviour.

Comment: smaller arrays may have good alignment while big arrays may not have that. to elliminate that, you can allocate size+4096 bytes for buffer and start copying from the first 4096 aligned element. is that a graph of non-pinned buffer for all data points? Maybe pci-e is capable of 9GB/s but card can't keepup with that unless data fits in its cache? If data fits in cache, maybe it is directly taken from there? Gap between 9GBs and 6GBs is halved for every doubled data size. Seems like a cache(1MB) effect

Comment: gpu has 1.5MB cache according to http://gpu.cs.uct.ac.za/Slides/Kepler2.pdf and you are reading it many times. Try reading different buffer locations at each iteration